# Print nubers 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21 from a given range using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

All I need is a for loop that'll print specific numbers from a given range.

I was thinking of starting off with a basic for loop and it'll print the whole range, but I only need numbers 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21. What else do I need?

```
  for (i: Int in 1..21) {

     println(i)
  }
```

Comment: What is the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numbers that you want to print are the first 6 members of the sequence:

> a(n) = n * (n + 1) /2

So you could print them with this loop:

```
for (i: Int in 1..6) {
    println(i * (i + 1) / 2)
}
```

or:

```
(1..6).forEach { println(it * (it + 1) / 2) }
```

Comment: Perfect! It makes sense to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i: Int in 1..21) {
  when (i) {
    1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21 -> println(i)
  }
}
```

However, this totally doesn’t make any sense.